# How to use Box with Java null values

Tags: scala, lift

I use a Java method that returns an object or `null` if a value was not found. So I need to check for null values:

```
val value = javaobject.findThing(xyz)
if(value != null) {
    value.doAnotherThing()
} else {
    warn("Value not found.")
}
```

Can I write this code shorter with the Box concept? I have read the [Lift-Wiki-documentation about the Box concept](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Box), but I don't understand how to use it with Java null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@TimN is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172289/lift-beginner-how-to-use-box-with-java-null-values#comment11547603_9172354), you could use `Box(value)` to create a `Box` from a possibly `null` value, but you'll get a deprecation warning.

```
scala> val v: Thing = null
v: Thing = null

scala> Box[Thing](v)
<console>:25: warning: method apply in trait BoxTrait is deprecated: Use legacyNullTest
              Box[Thing](v)
```

While you could use `Box.legacyNullTest`, if this is what you're doing, then I would just stick with the standard library and use [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option).

```
Option(javaobject.findThing(xyz)) match {
    case Some(thing) => thing.doAnotherThing()
    case _ => warn("Value not found.")
}
```

And if you needed a `Box` to pass around, `Option` will automagically convert to a `Box`:

```
scala> val b: Box[Thing] = Option(v)
b: net.liftweb.common.Box[Thing] = Empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Scala's `Option`, you can simply call `Box()` and pass in the value that may or may not be null, and you'll get a `Box` object that can be used normally. For example:

```
Box(javaobject.findThing(xyz)) match {
    case Full(thing) => thing.doAnotherThing()
    case _ => warn("Value not found.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, the example was very helpful for me.

Comment: You shouldn't use Box.apply with null values. null is actually a valid value inside a Box. If javaobject.findThing(xyz) returns null the result wil be Full(null). What you need is Box.legacyNullTest

Comment: Indeed, it does appear that the apply() methods of Box were changed in 2.4. Apologies for the incorrect information - you should accept the answer from @dave instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Box.legacyNullTest`. This method encapsulates any object in a Box in a null-safe manner:

```
def legacyNullTest[T](in: T): Box[T] = in match {
  case null => Empty
  case _ => Full(in)
}
```

`Box` returned from `legacyNullTest` can be later used as usual in for comprehensions or in pattern matching:

```
for {
  fragment <- Box.legacyNullTest(uri.getFragment)
yield {
  doSth(fragment)
}
```

or

```
Box.legacyNullTest(uri.getFragment) match {
  case Full(fragment) =>
    doSth(fragment)
  case _ =>
    log.error("Missing fragment part")
    doSthElse
}
```